# .NET remoting timing out when deployed to single AWS EC2 instance

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, .net-remoting

My team is planning to move on prem .NET application to AWS cloud on single EC2 instance. This application uses .NET remoting to communicate with other Web API application.

We are seeing remote timeout exception every time our application tries to communicate with other application which is also present on the same EC2 instance. This communication works if we specify the `localhost` while communicating to the other Web API application but not when we specify the `CNAME`.

What is the solution to this issue with .NET remoting on AWS EC2 instance?